Set 'treatZeroAs' for the Map chart (amCharts 4)
I have a Map chart in the project with a heat map feature on. In heatRules I use the logarithmic fill pattern which turns out doesn't work when there are states that have 0 in their value property.
// ...
heatRules: [
  {
    target: 'mapPolygons.template',
    property: 'fill',
    min: minColor,
    max: maxColor,
    logarithmic: true,
  },
],
// ...

Without 0 values

With 0 values

I found on stack overflow a similar question, answer of which states that there's a property treatZeroAs that can be set to chart's value axis to make logarithmic work with 0 values. But I don't know how can I set this property for the Map chart.
Could someone point me to the right direction, please?
